# Javafx program GUI not correctly display in raspbian

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've used this command to execute `sudo /opt/jdk8/bin/java -jar axulfxx.jar` the program. It is working but the problem is the GUI of program is not correctly display just like a TV that has a poor signal.

I've done lots of solutions but still no luck.

Comment: There isn't enough information on what is happening. The description "just like a TV that has a poor signal" isn't concise enough. Does all the windows/controls show up but flicker or something? How do you prove that `aulfxx.jar` is working correctly?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I solve my own problem by add `DISPLAY=:0` after `/opt/jdk8/bin/java -Djavafx.platform=gtk2 -jar axulfxx.jar`.